# How to pause browser rendering until page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I've tried googling for this, but it seems most people want to make their page pause rendering from the server's end.

I'm just a user who's sick of the massive web sites people make today, and I think my browsing experience would improve significantly if I could make my browser display nothing until a page is completely loaded, and then display it in t's entirety, though I understand it might be difficult deciding if a page is truly "complete" at any given point.

This way, there'd be no skipping around while elements load, minimal slow/jaggy scrolling, and a generally complete sense of using the site as it was intended.

I don't care if some sites take a minute to load. It just seems to be a hard request. I tried things like adding custom CSS that adds `display: none` to body, plus a greasemonkey script that removes the style on `DOMContentLoaded`. But nothing seems to work well because of progressive rendering, or the site breaks, and maybe several other complicated reasons.

Can anyone help me do this to my browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> though I understand it might be difficult deciding if a page is truly "complete" at any given point

Not difficult... impossible.

Without knowing the developers' intentions, you won't be able to reliably know when a page is finished loading.  Some pages never finish loading, as they stream new data.

If reliability doesn't matter a whole lot, there are some clues you can use:

- Slower rate of network requests
- Fewer re-layouts
- Somewhat consistent DOM

How you implement these detections in your extension depends on the browser you're using.  From there, you'll want to tweak thresholds and timing to your liking.